# Nodejs file globbing behaving differently in deploy environment

Tags: node.js, operating-system, gruntjs, glob, grunt-contrib-concat

We have a front-end app that is compiled using grunt tasks. One of these tasks parses the dependencies from a view js file and then continues to traverse the dependency chain resulting in a list of js files that need to be included in the concat task. This is working as expected on every developers machine. Those machines are either running OSX or Arch Linux.

When our deploy server pulls the latest version of master and runs the compilation tasks, the files included in the dependency chain are different. There is absolutely no difference in the code being run in the deploy environment from that being run on a local machine. The deploy environment is running Ubuntu.

My questions are: is there a difference in how these environments process the current working directory that is not documented? Are there differences in how node glob traverses the file system on different OS's? What could possibly be going on here?

Comment: Posting your dependency-list-generating task code would make it a lot easier for you to solicit answers. With no actual information however, my speculation would be that the difference is probably due to how node is run on the server versus on your dev machines and the consequent working directory in each case. This is one reason why `__dirname` based references are usually preferred over `.cwd` references.

Comment: @pwnyexpress - did you ever find a solution to this behavior? I'm seeing similar behavior with an Ubuntu server.

Comment: @Duane I did, in fact. This ended up being a result of directory names in the root of the filesystem of the virtual environment being different than on our development machines. This caused some of our traversing to end up in directories it shouldn't. We fixed it by logging out all of the path resolutions during the build process and checking it against our regex.